# What is the graph of partial derivative, or how do I understand it intuitively?

Tags: partial-derivative, graphing-functions

Consider the graph of $f(x,y) = \sqrt{xy}$. Each coloured line depicts the curve $f(x,y) = k$ for different values of $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

[image: Fig]

The derivative is thought as the tangent. How do I think of the partial derivatives $\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}$ and $\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}$ in the graph?

Comment: The ratio of the partial derivatives will give the slope of the gradient vector, which points essentially from a point on one level set to the closest point on the next level set up (procided enough level sets are plotted to really see the shape of the graph). Another way to look at it is the gradient is perpendicular to the level curve (more precisely it is perpendicular to the tangent of the level curve).

Comment: Of course this just tells you about the direction of the gradient. What about its magnitude? The magnitude is related to how close together the level curves are: the gradient is bigger if the level curves are closer together.

Comment: Your picture is not the *graph*. The graph of $f$ is the surface $z=f(x,y)$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

The partial derivatives tell us how the function changes when only one variable is changed. For example, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ says how the value of $f$ will change if we increase $x$.

We can make sense of that in your graph. We fix a $y$ value and look at what happens as we move to the right along the $x$ axis. We can see that at $y=4$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is greater than at $y=2$ because the $k$ lines are closer together,